# How to pass required arguments in Google colab (Notebook)

Tags: parsing, arguments, google-colaboratory

I use google colab for execution.

In the following code, as all the arguments are passed by default. I can pass the args as an empty list, which can be seen from the last line:

```
DEFAULT_ENV_NAME = "PongNoFrameskip-v4"
MEAN_REWARD_BOUND = 19.5

parser.add_argument("--cuda", default=True, action="store_true", help="Enable cuda")
    
    parser.add_argument("--env", default=DEFAULT_ENV_NAME,
                        help="Name of the environment, default=" + DEFAULT_ENV_NAME)
    parser.add_argument("--reward", type=float, default=MEAN_REWARD_BOUND,
                        help="Mean reward boundary for stop of training, default=%.2f" % MEAN_REWARD_BOUND)
    args = parser.parse_args(args = [])
```

when I use *print(args)* I got:

```
Namespace(cuda=True, env='PongNoFrameskip-v4', reward=19.5)
```

Also when I execute the following code:

```
DEFAULT_ENV_NAME = "PongNoFrameskip-v4"

parser.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True, help="Model file to load")
parser.add_argument("-e", "--env", default=DEFAULT_ENV_NAME,
                    help="Environment name to use, default=" + DEFAULT_ENV_NAME)
parser.add_argument("-r", "--record", help="Directory to store video recording")
parser.add_argument("--no-visualize", default=True, action='store_false', dest='visualize',
                    help="Disable visualization of the game play")
args = parser.parse_args(args=['dqn_model'])
```

I am getting errors in syntax, which is because of the last line. I need to send required values for model argument (say dqn_model).
What is the correct syntax for passing the arguments?

I tried the following which gave me errors:

```
args = parser.parse_args(args=['dqn_model'])
args = parser.parse_args(args=[model='dqn_model'])
args = parser.parse_args(args=[m='dqn_model'])
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked out for me

use :

```
args = argparse.Namespace(cuda="Argument=required",env="PongNoFrameskip-v4",reward=19.5)
```

make sure you have added all the argument keys with their respective value.